# Installing Tomcat as limited user (Windows)

Tags: tomcat

Trying to run tomcat as a limited user on Windows means tomcat doesn't have write permissions to the logs directory. And idea how to solve that (running as admin is not a solution).

Answer (score 1):

Well, to run Tomcat with non-admin priviliges, if the issue is only with writing logs, you may:

1. You can change the path to log files, to a directory where you have write permissions
2. You may turn off the logging completeley *(not recommended)*

However, I don''t think it will completely solve the problem, if Windows have some restrictions like unix regd. port accesses.

**For e.g. Unix will not let you start it on port 80/443 (<1024) unless your have superuser privileges. So that is one artea you will need to check on.**

Comment: Windows doesn't restrict ports <1024

Comment: @theotherrecieve - Thanks for the insight.. as i mentioned I haave had my hands more into Linux than Win.